# "introduce to" takes an indirect object?

Tags: transitive-verbs, prepositional-objects

Quirk's *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* (p.1209) lists "introduce to" among ditransitive verbs that take an indirect object and a prepositional object (the latter serving as a direct object) (D2b).

I can recognize this construction in sentences that use a verb like "warn." For example: "Mary warned **John** *of the dangers*." This is like "Mary told John the presence of the dangers," where "John" is obviously the indirect object of the sentence.

But I don't see how "introduce to" could be interpreted in this way in sentences like, say, "I introduced **Mary** to Tom." It seems to me to take a direct object rather than an indirect object right after the object ("Mary" in the aforementioned sentence), with the prepositional object ("Tom") being the indirect object.

According to Quirk, other such verbs include  "advise about, punish for, thank for, prevent from, interest in , accuse of, convict of, convince of, deprive of, inform of, persuade if, relieve of, remind of, rob of, suspect of, warn of, congratulate on, confine to, introduce to, refer to, sentence to, subject to, treat to, charge with, compare with."

Comment: Please don't answer in comments

Comment: Why not? No other answers have been attracted.